# Displaying emojis programmatically in JSX (Gatbsy)

Tags: javascript, jsx, emoji

I have the following JSX code:

```
import * as React from 'react'

const CheeseIcons = ({ milk }) => {
  const milkoji = {
    Cow:'1F42E',
    Goat: '1F410'
  }

  const icon = "&#x" + milkoji.[milk] + ";";
  return (
    <main>
      <p>{icon}</p>
      <p>&#x1F42E;</p>
    </main>
  )
}

export default CheeseIcons
```

I am passing `Cow` correctly as `{milk}` - but in the first paragraph the text `&#x1F42E;` is displayed, whereas in the second paragraph the emoji  is displayed.

How do I get the emoji to be displayed in the first paragraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reconsideration, this question is not a clear duplicate because it deals specifically with emojis which can only be encoded in UTF-16 with surrogate pairs, which make the answers from the linked question unsuitable.

You would therefore do:

```
const CheeseIcons = ({ milk }) => {
  const milkoji = {
    Cow: 0x1F42E, // Attention
    Goat: 0x1F410
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <p>{String.fromCodePoint(milkoji[milk])}</p>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Note that we use `String.fromCodePoint` instead of `String.fromCharCode` as the values above are code points (but not valid UTF-16 bytes encoding these emojis).

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks a lot. How would that work with more complex emojis, say flags, that use two CharCodes together?

Comment: fromCodePoint (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) accepts multiple code points. You could store an array in your object for each emoji and then spread it into fromCodePoint (`fromCodePoint(...milkoji[milk]`). Please note that char codes are something very different from code points.